# Leaflet for non-geographic data (Cartesian coordinates) from R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sp

I'm trying to create an interactive plot with leaflet containing polygons.
The coordinates of these polygons are not longitude/latitudes but rather Cartesian x and y coordinates that represent a building floor plan.

For coordinates that are single digit numbers the results look good:

```
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(9, 8, 8, 9, 9), 
                    c(3, 3, 4, 4, 3)))

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1), 1L)
leaflet() %>% addPolygons(data = SpP)
```

[image: Good plot]

But when I increase all y coordinates by 100 things go wrong:

```
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(9, 8, 8, 9, 9), 
                    c(103, 103, 104, 104, 103)))

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1), 1L)
leaflet() %>% addPolygons(data = SpP)
```

[image: Bad plot]

I'm guessing this has to do with the default projection settings of the map. I tried initializing the map with these settings:

```
leaflet(options(crsClass = "L.CRS.Simple"))
```

After reading [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) example but with no success.

Comment: Does this work for you: `leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.Simple"))) %>% addPolygons(data = SpP)`?

Comment: Yes!! That does exactly what I want it to. Thanks a lot Hendrik!

Comment: Fwiw mapview will do this automatically for you. `mapview(SpP, native.crs = TRUE)` Note though that `L.CRS.Simple` does currently not work with raster images.